# Angular 2 broadcasting events to notify other components

Tags: android, angular

So I'm actually loosing my mind. I'm new to Angular 2 and I'm trying to understand how to let sibling child components comunicate between each other.

I have **n** child components that can play an **Audio** file.

The goal is to stop playing component if someone is started.

E.G. : component 1 is played, I play start on component 2, component 1 is stopped, component 2 is played.

I tried with shared service with no luck and also trying with `EventEmitter` comunicating from child to parent but it is not working.
I cannot figure out how to notify all components at once.

**RegistrationComponent** ( child )

```
import {Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter} from '@angular/core';
import {Path} from "./data-model";
import {MediaPlugin} from '@ionic-native/media';
import {Platform} from 'ionic-angular';
import {SocialSharing} from '@ionic-native/social-sharing';
import {RegistrationService} from './registration.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'registration',
  template: `
      <div class="reg__name">{{ url.name }}</div>
      <button ion-button color="secondary" item-right clear large (click)="toggle(url.path);">
        <ion-icon [name]="playing ? 'md-square' : 'md-play'"></ion-icon>
      </button>`,
  providers: [
    MediaPlugin,
    SocialSharing,
    RegistrationService
  ]
})

export class RegistrationComponent {

  @Input() url: Path;

  @Input() someonePlaying: boolean = false;

  @Output() onPlayed = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

  playing: boolean = false;

  mediaContainer: any;

  path: string;

  constructor(private media: MediaPlugin,
              private platform: Platform,
              private socialSharing: SocialSharing,
              private service: RegistrationService) {

    this.path = "assets/audio";

    // service.playing.subscribe(val => this.onSomeonePlaying(val));

  }

  ngOnChanges() {
    console.log(this.someonePlaying);
  }

  toggle(filename) {
    this.playing
      ? this.stop()
      : this.play(filename)
  }

  play(fileName) {
    const mp3URL = this.getMediaURL(`${this.path}/${fileName}`);
    this.mediaContainer = this.media.create(mp3URL);

    this.mediaContainer.play();
    this.playing = true;
    this.onPlayed.emit(true);
  }

  stop() {
    this.mediaContainer.stop();
    this.playing = false;
    // this.service.stop();
  }

  share() {
    this.socialSharing.shareViaWhatsApp("Condividi su Whatsapp", "", "");
  }

  onSomeonePlaying(val: boolean) {
    console.log(val);
  }

  getMediaURL(s) {
    let isAndroid = this.platform.is("android");
    return isAndroid ? `/android_asset/www/${s}` : s;
  }


}
```

**Portion of home.html that prints the components**

```
    <ion-item *ngFor="let url of currentUrls">
  <registration (onPlayed)="onPlayed($event)"
                [(someonePlaying)] = "globalPlaying"
                [url]="url"></registration>
</ion-item>
```

*home.ts**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {NavController} from 'ionic-angular';
import {Registrations, Registration} from './data-model';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})

export class HomePage {

  path: string;

  urls: Array<any>;

  currentUrls: Array<{name: string, path: string}>;

  globalPlaying: boolean = false;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

    this.path = "assets/audio";
    this.urls = Registrations;

    this.currentUrls = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < this.urls.length; i++) {
      this.currentUrls = this.currentUrls.concat(this.urls[i]["paths"]);
    }

  }

  onChange(key) {
    this.currentUrls = this.filter(key);
  }

  onPlayed(val){
    console.log("global playing", val);
    this.globalPlaying = true;
  }

  filter(key) {
    if (!key || key === "all")
      return this.findAll(this.urls);

    return this.findWhere(this.urls, key)["paths"];
  }

  findAll(collection) {
    let array = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
      array = array.concat(collection[i]["paths"]);
    }

    return array;
  }

  findWhere(collection, key) {
    for (let i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
      if (collection[i]["id"] === key)
        return collection[i];
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: You're definitely losing your mind... you forgot to include code so we can help you!

Comment: You're right too.

Answer (score 2):

You should `subscribe` to `EventEmitter` to catch the events. You need a service with an `EventEmitter`:

```
@Injectable()
export class MyService
{
    myEventEmiter:EventEmitter<void> = new EventEmitter<void>();
}
```

Then `inject` service into your component and subscribe to it to catch the events:

```
contsruct(protected myService:MyService){}

ngOnInit()
{
    this.myService.subscribe(
        () => { //An event occurs }
    );
}
```

At the other hand in another component you should `emit` the `EventEmitter` to create new event:

```
this.myService.emit();
```

Answer (score 0):

I used an event to notify other instances to hide, of my date-picker component.
Please follow
[event-broadcasting-in-angular-2](https://blog.lacolaco.net/post/event-broadcasting-in-angular-2/)

You have to create a broadcaster and messageEvent.